# Multivariate transformation formula correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Just need confirmation that the following theorem is correct.

Let $X$ be a continuously distributed $n$-variate random variable with density $\varrho_X$ and $f : \mathrm{R}^n \rightarrow \mathrm{R}^n$ a continuously  differentiable function. For the density $\varrho_{f(X)}$ of $f(X)$ it holds
\begin{align*}
\varrho_{f(X)}(y) = \int_{f^{-1}(y)} \frac{\varrho_X(x)}{\left| \det D f(x) \right|} \,V(\mathrm{d} x).
\end{align*}

**Edit:**
Was definitely not correct. Maybe

$$\varrho_{ f(\boldsymbol X)}(\boldsymbol y) =
\int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(\boldsymbol y - f(\boldsymbol x))
 \varrho_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol x) d\boldsymbol x =
\sum_{\boldsymbol x : f(\boldsymbol x)= \boldsymbol y} \frac{\varrho_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol x)}{
 \left| \det D  f(\boldsymbol x) \right|} \,\boldsymbol{1}_{\det D  f(\boldsymbol x) \neq 0}(\boldsymbol x)\ ?$$
This reduces correctly to the univariate and diffeomorphic case.

Comment: Quick sanity check: what if $f(x)=x$ (identity function)?

Comment: Correct, but only if the integral over a single point is the integrand at that point.

Comment: But it isn't, it's zero.

Comment: Right, maybe treating these cases separately or modifying the integral.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_vector

Comment: Thanks, updated it. Still trying to figure out what the differential $V(dx)$ is and what happens for $f=$identity.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a formula for $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. If $\nabla f \neq 0$ on the surface $f(\boldsymbol x) = y$, then
$$\varrho_{f(\boldsymbol X)}(y) =
\int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(y - f(\boldsymbol x))
 \varrho_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol x) d\boldsymbol x =
\int_{f(\boldsymbol x) = y} \frac
 {\varrho_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol x)} {| \nabla f(\boldsymbol x)|}
 dS(\boldsymbol x).$$

If $\boldsymbol f$ is $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, then $\delta(\boldsymbol y - \boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol x))$ is a product of $n$ factors $\delta(y_i - f_i(\boldsymbol x))$. Assuming $\boldsymbol f$ has a smooth inverse in a neighborhood of $\boldsymbol x$ if $\boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol x) = \boldsymbol y$,
$$\varrho_{\boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol X)}(\boldsymbol y) =
\int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(\boldsymbol y - \boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol x))
 \varrho_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol x) d\boldsymbol x =
\sum_{\boldsymbol x: \boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol x) = \boldsymbol y}
 \frac {\varrho_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol x)}
  {\left| \det D \boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol x) \right|}.$$

These can be viewed as special cases of the same general formula
$$\varrho_{\boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol X)}(\boldsymbol y) =
\int_{\mathbb R^n} \delta(\boldsymbol y - \boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol x))
 \varrho_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol x) d\boldsymbol x =
\int_{\boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol x) = \boldsymbol y} \frac
 {\varrho_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol x)}
 {\sqrt {\det (J J^t)}} dS(\boldsymbol x),$$
where $J = D \boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol x)$ is the $k \times n$ Jacobian matrix of $\boldsymbol f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^k$ and the integral is over an $(n - k)$-dimensional surface.

For $k > n$, we get a degenerate distribution: the pdf contains $k - n$ delta functions that haven't been integrated out.

Comment: The problem is that $f$ is not a diffeomorphism which is the easy case.

Comment: The easier cases are also given here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities

Comment: There are some obvious generalizations. $\varrho_{X^2}(y) = \int_{\mathbb R} \delta(y - x^2) \varrho_X(x) dx$ still holds but evaluates to a sum over the two inverse functions.

Comment: Right, in the one-dimensional case, but what does it look like in higher dimensions?

Comment: The integral is unchanged. Then you need to split the integral into pieces to which you can apply the u-substitution.

Comment: Sure, but how does a closed formula look like?

Comment: For something like $\sin X$, you'll get an infinite number of pieces. There won't be a closed form for general $\varrho_X$.

Comment: I was hoping to extend this $$\varrho_{f(\boldsymbol X)}(y) =
\sum_{x : f(x) = y} \frac
 {\varrho_{\boldsymbol X}(x)} {| f'(x)|}$$ to the multivariate case.

Comment: I get it. For scalar valued $f$ uncountably many values are attained by $f^{-1}(y)$ such that the integral is needed for one piece. For vector valued $f$ countably many values are attained giving many pieces.